# Does anyone know why my router is different

Tags: router, ip

I was looking at my IP and it says it is a 10.0.0.1. how do I change it back to a 192.x.x.x and what does is a 10.0.0.1 IP?

Comment: 10.x.x.x and 192.168.x.x are both private IP address blocks which are assigned by your DHCP enabled router. The router itself gets an IP address first. Then it gets an IP address block and whenever a device joins the network, then it assigns an unassigned IP address to the device. And when a devices leaves the network, the IP address is unsigned and saved back to the address pool. Letting DHCP manage your network is much easier than assigning static TCP/IP settings to each device on network. This ranges varies from router to router, and you cannot change it even you assign static IP address.

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan is correct: this is no issue. This IP range is still a private IP range and shouldn't cause any problems. Unless you have a very specific reason to do so, there is no reason to change your default IP range.

Answer (score 1):

There are three private-use IPv4 address ranges: 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, and 192.168.0.0/16. All of them **work identically** and your devices won't care which one is being used; for home networks it's mostly a matter of preference.

So maybe whoever configured your router thought that 10.x *looks nicer* than 192.168.

(The only real difference is that 10./8 is the largest of those ranges and 192.168./16 is the smallest one – in other words it's 10.x.y.z vs 192.168.x.y, one lets you freely choose three numbers, the other only gives you two at most. This still doesn't matter at home but can be quite useful if your LAN spans several floors or even several buildings.)

Most routers will have a page in their configuration screen where you can change their LAN interface's IP address to whatever you want. (If the router offers DHCP don't forget to change the DHCP range as well.) Be careful to use the correct range – only 192.168.x.x is reserved for private use, but the rest of 192.x.x.x *is not.*